# How to get the value of checkboxes that are checked by using the form object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I am a beginner at Javascript and I have a problem with my Javascript form objects. How do I loop through the entire form object select only the elements that are checked by the user. So far I have tried the following:

```
//Gets the selected checkbox values:
function getCbValues() {

    var chkMouse = document.getElementById("chkMouse");
    var chkKeyboard = document.getElementById("chkKeyboard");
    var chkDVD = document.getElementById("chkDVD");
    var chkSound = document.getElementById("chkSound");
    var myFormElem = myForm.elements;

    for (var i = 0; i < myFormElem.length; i++) {
        if (myFormElem[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (myFormElem.checked == true) {
                if (myFormElem[i].elementId == chkMouse) {
                    alert("This is the Mouse");
                }
                if (myFormElem[i].elementId == chkKeyboard) {
                    alert("This is the Keyboard");
                }
                if (myFormElem[i].elementId == chkDVD) {
                    alert("This is the DVD");
                }
                if (myFormElem[i].elementId == chkSound) {
                    alert("This is the Sound");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Nothing");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have declared all the var for all the different checkbox Id's. Here is the html:

```
<form action="" name="form1">
 <!--Checkbox table-->
    <table>
        <!--Select Add on Item's-->
        <tr class="firstHeader">
            <th colspan="3">
                <h3>Select Add On Items (Optional):</h3>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Add On Items</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Mouse</label>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkMouse" value="Mouse" id="chkMouse" price="31" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Keyboard</label></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkKeyboard" value="Keyboard" id="chkKeyboard" price="42" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>DVD Rome Drive</label></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkDVD" value="DVD Rome Drive" id="chkDVD" price="56" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Sound Card</label></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkSound" value="Sound Card" id="chkSound" price="83" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

As you can see I have put the form into a table. But my issue is that whenever I run the Javascript the returned value is always null or undefined. My question is that how can I make a form object in Javascript loop over all these elements and in the end only return the values of the checkboxes that are checked. Can someone help me with this issue please. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: There is no form here, there are a bunch of input elements in a table. Wrap the table in form tags. Where is *myForm* declared or initialised? Forms have an [*elements* collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) that lists all the controls in the form, you can loop over that. You might want to start here: [Web forms — Working with user data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms).

Comment: BTW, you can use `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked` to get all the checked checkboxes. https://jsbin.com/jerutig/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get nothing returned is because your getCbValues() function is not getting called anywhere in the code you have shown. Even if it was it would only show the current state as you haven't set up anything to respond to changes.

What I would do is set up event listeners to detect when a checkbox is checked and then do something with that information. You should do that outside of any function.

You can set an event listener like this:

```
var chkMouse = document.getElementById("chkMouse");
chkMouse.addEventListener('change', () => {
        alert('this is the mouse')
      })
```

Assuming you want to submit your form with the checked data you would probably add the item to an array that is then submitted as form data on submit.

Additionally you would want to check whether someone un-checks your item. You could do that like this:

```
chkMouse.addEventListener('change', () => {
        if (chkMouse.checked) {
          alert('mouse added')
        } else {
          alert('mouse removed')
        }
      })
```